# Different spacing for same enumerate in and out the tcolorbox

Tags: spacing, lists, tcolorbox, enumitem

Here in the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=1in, top=.25in, bottom=1.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{%
  fontspec,
  parskip,
  lastpage,
  booktabs,
  polyglossia,
  graphicx, 
  fancyhdr,
  lato
}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\setmainfont{Lato}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\setlength{\headheight}{1.15in}
\setlength{\headsep}{.15in}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\lhead{\footnotesize{Hello\\Hello }}
\rhead{}
\rfoot{}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}

\begin{document}
  \begin{center}
      \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced jigsaw,opacityback=0,sharp corners]
        \begin{enumerate}
          \item This is 1
          \item This is 2
        \end{enumerate}
      \end{tcolorbox}
  \end{center}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item This is 1
      \item This is 2
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The enumerate spacing between items in and out the tcolorbox is different.

How do I get the spacing in tcolorbox to be the same as that out the tcolorbox (the default spacing between items)?

Comment: So which spacing do you want? The inner can be achieved by setting `noitemsep` for lists. For the outer you would have to set `\itemsep`. Btw: Do not use `center` around a `tcolorbox`.

Comment: Sorry I thought I had commented in your other question about this but I must have got distracted and then forgot.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Not a problem. I thought a new question would be useful, anyway. And thanks for your reply here. Works perfectly.

Comment: @TeXnician I could have explicitly mentioned it. But I was aiming to get the 'default' spacing in the lists, i.e. out the tcolorbox. I have edited the question to include this. And thanks for pointing out redundant center environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the parskip package but tcolorbox uses internally a minipage which resets parskip. If you want as spacing the one you get outside the box you can avoid the change of the inner spacing with the `parbox=false` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=1in, top=.25in, bottom=1.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{%
  fontspec,
  parskip,
  lastpage,
  booktabs,
  polyglossia,
  graphicx,
  fancyhdr,
  lato
}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\setmainfont{Lato}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\setlength{\headheight}{1.15in}
\setlength{\headsep}{.15in}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\lhead{\footnotesize{Hello\\Hello }}
\rhead{}
\rfoot{}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}

\begin{document}
  \begin{center}
      \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced jigsaw,opacityback=0,sharp corners,parbox=false]
        \begin{enumerate}
          \item This is 1
          \item This is 2
        \end{enumerate}
      \end{tcolorbox}
  \end{center}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item This is 1
      \item This is 2
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can simply achieve the inner spacing by setting `noitemsep` using `enumitem`. (Btw: I've removed the unnecessary `center` environment.)

[image: list spacing]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, portrait, margin=1in, top=.25in, bottom=1.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{%
  fontspec,
  parskip,
  lastpage,
  booktabs,
  polyglossia,
  graphicx, 
  fancyhdr,
  lato
}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\setmainfont{Lato}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\setlength{\headheight}{1.15in}
\setlength{\headsep}{.15in}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}
\lhead{\footnotesize{Hello\\Hello }}
\rhead{}
\rfoot{}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1}
\setlist[enumerate]{noitemsep}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced jigsaw,opacityback=0,sharp corners]
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item This is 1
        \item This is 2
      \end{enumerate}
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \begin{enumerate}
      \item This is 1
      \item This is 2
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```